# c# crystal reports database logon error when deployed (works fine on dev-machine)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, deployment, crystal-reports, report

i've created a crystal report (version 2008) to extract data from a sql 2008 server. has about 10 subreports. works perfectly fine in the crystal designer. 
now i wanted to write a small c# programm to run the report via the crystal runtime, to get in deployed on a different system.

here roughly the c# code

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    RunReport(Convert.ToInt32(args[0]), args[1].ToString());
}

static void RunReport(int StoerungID, string version) {
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();

    report.Load(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["report_basis"]);


    Console.WriteLine("set parameters...");
    report.SetParameterValue("ID", StoerungID);
    report.SetParameterValue("Version", version);

    report.SetDatabaseLogon("user","...");

    string export_filename = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["report_export_prefix"] + StoerungID + ".pdf";

    Console.WriteLine("export report to {0}", export_filename);
    report.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, export_filename);
    report.Close();
}
```

works perfectly fine on my dev-machine. as soon as i deploy the exe including the crystal runtime file to a target machine i get logon-errors.

> Warning: ORB::BOA_init: hostname lookup returned `localhost' (127.0.0.1/::1) Use the -OAhost option to select some other hostname
>   set parameters... export report to
>   ...\Stoerung_6561.pdf   Unhandled Exception: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: Date
>   nbankanmeldung fehlgeschlagen. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Datenbankanmeldung
>   fehlgeschlagen.    at
>   ...

it roughly says "database logon failed". i thought the database connection is stored in the report? 
removing the subreports didnt help. i used the crystal report runtime, downloaded from the SAP-website.

it is c# 4.5 in vs2012 and crystal report 2008.

any thoughts? whats going wrong? Is it the correct way to handle this???
any help would be highly welcome...

update: the edited code gives the same Logon-Error as before:

```
static void RunReport(int StoerungID, string version) {
    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();

    Console.WriteLine("load report {0}", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["report_basis"]);
    report.Load(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["report_basis"]);

    foreach (CrystalDecisions.Shared.IConnectionInfo ci in report.DataSourceConnections) {
        Console.WriteLine("IConnnectionInfo: Servername: {0}, Databasename: {1}", ci.ServerName, ci.DatabaseName);
        ci.SetConnection("DBSERVER", "INITIALCATALOG",
                         "user","passwd");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("set parameters...");
    report.SetParameterValue("StoerungID", StoerungID);
    report.SetParameterValue("Version", version);

    string export_filename = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["report_export_prefix"] + StoerungID + ".pdf";

    Console.WriteLine("export report to {0}", export_filename);
    report.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, export_filename);
    report.Close();
}
```

Comment: The database connection is not stored in the report, you still need to specify the `DataSource` of the `ReportDocument`. Can you see where it is looking for the database? I have seen this error when the path to the database has been incorrect.

Comment: what do you mean with "where it is looking for the database"? what ihave seen is, thats not even connecting to the database, since i tried to have a look in the sql-profiler to see, which credentials its been using.